# Как сделать отправленный файл в виде ссылки?

Tags: java, android, файлы, download

Пишу мессенджер, сейчас добавил возможность отправить файл в сообщении, но пока у меня эти файлы отображаются в виде строки текста (название и размер) , как мне сделать так, чтоб файл можно было скачать, чтоб это был такой же текст, но при нажатии файл качался на телефон. Какую технологию можно использовать, может где то есть пример?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно ссылку сделать кликабельной. Для этого есть утилита `Linkify` в пакете `android.text.util`

```
Linkify.addLinks(tvLink, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```